# Can I force a class to be inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following class:

```
//! Counter class base. Must be inherited.
class base_seeded_counter
{
public:
    //! Destructor
    virtual ~base_seeded_counter() { };

    //! Get the next value.
    int get_next();

protected:
    //! Override the counter next value.
    void set_next(const int next);

private:
    int m_next_value;    // Next value.
}

// ------------------------------------------------------

inline int base_seeded_counter::get_next()
{
    return m_next_value++;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------

inline void base_seeded_counter::set_next(const int next)
{
    m_next_value = next;
}
```

The purpose of this class is to implement a base counter object with the intention that it must be inherited. It does not have any virtual methods other than the destructor and, more importantly, *does not initialize the `m_next_value` member*. This is the job of the derived class. For example:

```
class file_seeded_counter : public base_seeded_counter
{
public:
    file_seeded_counter(const std::string &file_name);

    void reseed();

private:
    std::string m_file_name;
}

inline int file_seeded_counter::file_seeded_counter(const std::string &file_name) :
    m_file_name(file_name)
{
    reseed();
}

inline void file_seeded_counter::reseed()
{
    int seed_from_file;

    // open file here and get seed value...

    set_next(seed_from_file);
}
```

This class, deriving from base_seeded_counter reads the initial counter value from a file, and offers the ability to re-read the seed from the file via the `reseed()` method. There may be other classes that offer similar functionality to seed from databases, network sources, or a PRNG, for example.

My question is this: Given that I have no pure virtual methods, does C++ offer a mechanism to prevent someone from creating an instance of `base_seeded_counter`?

Comment: Can I ask you **why** do you want to achieve that? If you create an abstract class why would it bother you if it would get instantiated?

Comment: @majster - Good question. The class in my example is technically abstract, but because all its methods are implemented, the compiler sees it as a concrete class. What the compiler doesn't see is that `m_next_value` is never initialized, which could lead to some serious issues when the counter doesn't return the expected result. My interest lies in ensuring that other developers can't do something silly like this: `base_seeded_counter foo;` and have their code break.

Comment: Don't depend on derived classes to initialize `m_next_value`. Initialize it to something sane, such as `0`, in the base class and let derived classes reset it to a value of their choosing.

Comment: Create a protected ctor with no parameter that does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you already have a virtual destructor, the obvious way would be to declare it pure virtual. It's entirely legitimate to have a pure virtual destructor that's also defined in the base class:

```
class base_seeded_counter {
public:
    virtual ~base_seeded_counter() = 0;
    int get_next();
protected:
    void set_next(const int next);
private:
    int m_next_value;
}

inline virtual base_seeded_counter::~base_seeded_counter() {}
```

Defining the destructor this way doesn't change the fact that it's a pure virtual, so this class can't be instantiated.

---

As an aside, the comments you currently have in the code are 100% useless visual noise. A comment of `get next` on a function named `get_next` adds nothing useful at all.

Comment: Another excellent solution. Thanks! BTW the comments are not like that in the actual code, I should have just removed them completely in the example :-)

Comment: I selected this as the answer because it is how I chose to implement my final solution (my class did not already have a constructor, but it did have a virtual destructor). Both solutions are absolutely valid though.

Comment: _@Jerry_ Bit more lengthy and harder to understand solution than mine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's a bit longer, I'm not sure I'd agree about harder to understand though--rather the contrary, it's a pretty common idiom that anybody who knows C++ should recognize almost without having to think about it at all.

Comment: @Jerry Most people don't get that thing right, that you have to define a body for a pure virtual destructor (in contrary to any other pure virtual functions). That's what I'm referring to. One should know that though, absolutely agreed.

Answer (score 13):

> My question is this: Given that I have no pure virtual methods, does C++ offer a mechanism to prevent someone from creating an instance of `base_seeded_counter`?

Yes, give it a `protected` default constructor (may be empty).

Comment: Consise solutions to simple problems make me all warm and fuzzy inside. Thanks!